# se restablece la conexion websocket?

Tags: javascript, websocket

estoy experimentando con web sockets y quisiera saber si cada vez que recargo la pagina se volveria generar una instancia nueva websocket .. o si una vez que se establecio seguiria activa mientras navego por la web?
Es que quiero hacer un sistemade notificaciones y quiero poner el socket en una main.js y como no tengo como escuchar los eventos de la base de datos en mysql desde el servidor.. tengo que generar consultas desde el cliente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si tu refrescas tu pagina o la cierras, la conexión se rompe, por lo que se actualmente no hay otra manera que te impida mantener la relación estable, esa es la manera en que trabajas con los WebSockets.

Comment: q sad buen gracias bro pro la data. Creo que no me quedara otra forma de implementarlo , tendra que ser asi. Mi problema viene cuando tengo que notificar al usuario en si .. tendre que buscar una forma de hacer referencia mas concreta en el arreglo de cleintes conectados.